# Difficulty with methods

Tags: java

My code seems to be working partially: What I mean is that when I don't enter a leap year for example 99 end then i choose 2 for february it prints 29 days,I would like to print 28 I have 2 separete methods, one to check if the year is leap or not and the other one to print the days in month so if someone know how to repair the program to be more efficient and for not leap year to display 28 days I would be grateful. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LeapYearCheck
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        LeapYearCheck.isLeapYear();
        LeapYearCheck.daysInMonth();
    }

    static void isLeapYear()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();

        if(year % 4 == 0 || year % 400 ==0) 
        {
            System.out.println(year + " is leap year:");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(year + " is not leap year:");
        }
    }

    static void daysInMonth()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a month :");
        int month = input.nextInt();

        if (month == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("There are 29 days in February: ");
        }
        else if(month == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in January ");
        }
        else if(month == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 28 days in February ");
        }
        else if(month == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in March ");
        }
        else if(month == 4)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in April");
        }
        else if(month == 5)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in May ");
        }
        else if(month == 6)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in June  ");
        }
        else if(month == 7)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in July  ");
        }
        else if(month == 8)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in August ");
        }
        else if(month == 9)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in September  ");
        }
        else if(month == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in  October ");
        }
        else if(month == 11)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in November ");
        }
        else if(month == 12)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in December ");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Month, Please enter a number between 1 & 12 Merci: ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? You could achieve this in a much cleaner way using joda and its `DateTime` class.

Comment: Are you free to use Java libraries? plus please replace the if-else with switch-case as a starter.

Answer (score 2):

Your leap year check is wrong. You should use

```
if((year%100 != 0 && year%4 == 0) || year % 400 ==0))
```

Comment: thank you hovanessyan it seems that your solution is working better

Answer (score 2):

It will always print

> There are 29 days in February:

Because the **first** check is as follows:

```
if (month == 2)
            {
            System.out.println("There are 29 days in February: ");
            }
```

Plus, the correct way to check leap year:

```
if ((year % 400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)) {
   //Leap year.

}
```

Correct code:

```
if (month == 2) {
    if (LeapYearCheck.isLeapYear()) {
        System.out.println("There are 29 days in this month.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("There are 28 days in this month.");
    }
}
```

Make your `isLeapYear()` function return a `boolean` (and not a `void`).

Comment: what can I do in order to print 29 days for leap year and 28 when the year is not leap, i know how to do it when it is in one method , but when they are separete i don't know

Comment: thank you The Elite Gentlemen is there a way to combine the if else statements to make them more efficient, like to have one for 30 days one for 31 and one for the others?

Comment: @Kiril: Not really. My suggestion would be separating the calculating and the printing in two parts. The first method just has to return the number of months and the second method just calls that to print the message (doing things this ways protects you from repeating "Thera are ... days in ..." over and over)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to hovanessyan's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953563/difficulty-with-methods/7953618#7953618), take into account that the information on whether the year is a leap year or not is kept and lost in the scope of the `isLeapYear` function. This function should, for instance, return a boolean, and be called inside `daysInMonth`, so `daysInMonth` could return 28 or 29 accordingly. Using a `Map` could also help simplify the huge if-else block.

Comment: That just makes the tangled mess worse, now, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed. It's such an overwhelming mess. Fixed it to, at least, not increase the magnitude of the tragedy?

Comment: I would like to thank to everyone for your time and effort. I really appreciate it, as there is noone else to ask!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: the `daysInMonth()` method needs to know what year it is, and then if the month number is 2, it needs to check if it's a leap year. Modify both your methods to accept the year and/or month as arguments rather than prompt for them, then prompt for the year and month in `main()` and pass the necessary data to each method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all u entered 29 days if month number is 2.

```
if (month == 2)
        {
        System.out.println("There are 29 days in February: ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code....

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class LeapYearCheck {
 static boolean isleep;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     LeapYearCheck.isLeapYear(); LeapYearCheck.daysInMonth(); 
     } 
 static void isLeapYear() {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a year: "); 
     int year = input.nextInt();

        if(year % 4 == 0 || year % 400 ==0) 
        {
            isleep=true;
        System.out.println(year + " is leap year:");
        }
        else 
        {
            isleep=false;
            System.out.println(year + " is not leap year:");
        }
    }
        static void daysInMonth()
        {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a month :");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        if (month == 2)
        {
            if(isleep)
             System.out.println("There are 29 days in February: ");
            else 
                System.out.println("There are 28 days in February: ");
        }
        else    if(month == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in January ");
        }

        else if(month == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in March ");
        }
        else if(month == 4)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in April");
        }
        else if(month == 5)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in May ");
        }
        else if(month == 6)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in June  ");
        }
        else if(month == 7)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in July  ");
        }
        else if(month == 8)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in August ");
        }
        else if(month == 9)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in September  ");
        }
        else if(month == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in  October ");
        }
        else if(month == 11)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in November ");
        }
        else if(month == 12)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in December ");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Month, Please enter a number between 1 & 12 Merci: ");
        }
        }
```

}

Comment: When you enter the year and the month you need to enter again year and month instead of giving you the result after the first input

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LeapYearCheck
{
   public static boolean leap=false;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    LeapYearCheck.leap=LeapYearCheck.isLeapYear();
    LeapYearCheck.daysInMonth();
}
    static boolean isLeapYear()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();

        if(year % 4 == 0 || year % 400 ==0) 
        {
        System.out.println(year + " is leap year:");
        return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(year + " is not leap year:");return false;
        }return false;
    }
        static void daysInMonth()
        {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a month :");
        int month = input.nextInt();
           if(month == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in January ");
        }
        else if(month == 2)
        {if(leap==true){
            System.out.println("The are 29 days in February ");}
         else{System.out.println("The are 28 days in February ");}} 
        }
        else if(month == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in March ");
        }
        else if(month == 4)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in April");
        }
        else if(month == 5)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in May ");
        }
        else if(month == 6)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in June  ");
        }
        else if(month == 7)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in July  ");
        }
        else if(month == 8)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in August ");
        }
        else if(month == 9)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in September  ");
        }
        else if(month == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in  October ");
        }
        else if(month == 11)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in November ");
        }
        else if(month == 12)
        {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in December ");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Month, Please enter a number between 1 & 12 Merci: ");
        }
        }
```

}

You can just check. I haven't compiled it

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the year as well as the month to compute the number of days:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
    int year = input.nextInt();
    if (LeapYearCheck.isLeapYear(year)) {
        System.out.println(year + " is leap year:");
    } else {
        System.out.println(year + " is not leap year:");
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a month :");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("There are " + daysInMonth(year, month) + " in month");
}

static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return (year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
}

static int daysInMonth(int year, int month) {
    if (month == 1) {
        return 31;
    } else if (month == 2) {
        if (isLeapYear(year)) {
            return 29;
        } else {
            return 28;
        }
    } else if (month == 3) {
        return 31;
    } else if (month == 4) {
        return 30;
    } else if (month == 5) {
        return 31;
    } else if (month == 6) {
        return 30;
    } else if (month == 7) {
        return 31;
    } else if (month == 8) {
        return 31;
    } else if (month == 9) {
        return 30;
    } else if (month == 10) {
        return 31;
    } else if (month == 11) {
        return 30;
    } else if (month == 12) {
        return 31;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid Month, Please enter a number between 1 & 12 Merci: ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.Calendar class and you will be fine all the time.